# FatalErrorException in Handler.php line 26

Tags: laravel-5

Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::report() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php on line 73 and defined in \app\Exceptions\Handler.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(73): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Error))
#2 {main}
thrown

I have migrated one application from laravel 4.2 to laravel 5.0, placed all the code according to requirement and done composer update command but white executing this I am getting this error.
Deleted the composer.lock file and vendor directly and done the composer update still getting this error.